# Remove Gradient at Android Bar Control

Tags: android, user-interface

Does anyone know how can I remove this gradient highlighted in red? I'm using the theme Light.NoTitleBar".

[image: With Gradient]

Comment: Is that a shadow from the notification bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a custom theme in res/values/styles.xml that looks like this:

```
<!-- No Activity DropShadow -->
<style name="Theme.NoTitleOrDrop" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

And then reference it in your manifest like this:

```
<application
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.NoTitleOrDrop"
    android:name="@string/app_name>
    ...
```

This should get rid of that top shadow. You can use this theme on a per Activity basis or in Application like I did in the example to work on all Activities.